# Safari JSON error from jQuery serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, safari

I have a weird bug happening in Safari.

**On submit:** I am using `jQuery.serialize();` to serialize my submitted form data.

From there, I am sending it to a script using AJAX. This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari is complaining about invalid JSON format.

Here is the `.on('submit'...)` function:

```
jQuery('form#header-register').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var userData = jQuery(this).serialize();

     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"action": "user-register", userData},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data === 1) {    
                wpUserLoggedIn = 1;
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                wpUserLoggedIn = 0;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The error coming from Safari is:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'userData'.`

This bug is preventing other scripts on the page from firing. Is there another method to serialize form data that will work with Safari?

Would it be smarter to put the `action` in a hidden form field and pass that through with serialize as well?

Comment: jQuery.serialize does not produce JSON formatted data.

Comment: You're right, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Nope, you didn't. You're still mixing JSON and URL-encoded stuff. You cannot just do `data: {"action": "user-register", userData}`

Comment: Apparently you can in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
data: {"action": "user-register", "userData": userData},
```

as it is complaining about not seeing a `:`

I guess the other browsers are implying this themselves

Comment: You're right, this worked. It appears Chrome and Firefox were in fact implying it themselves. I love/hate how they do that. Nice it would work either way, but sucks it wouldn't tell me thats incorrect format. I'll accept this answer in a few minutes.

Comment: This is why I only develop for lynx.